# insert photos into database from phone (android)

Tags: android, sql-server, delphi, firemonkey

Is there a component in *Delphi* (for *Android*) that I can use to insert a photo from my photos stored on the phone into my application (also on the phone)? 
Something like *devexpress* has for the *VCL* (`cxImage`).

I would like to be able to upload a photo from my phone storage into that component and then save it to database.
I tried using *TMS FMX UI Pack* but it's terribly buggy, next to useless.

Is there any way I can do this ?

Comment: Did you give FireDAC components a try?

Comment: FireDAC does not support connection to SQL Server in android.

Answer (score 0):

As you know, [*FireDAC* components do only support direct access on *Interbase ToGo*- and *SQLite*-databases for mobile devices](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Mobile_Tutorial:_Using_FireDAC_and_SQLite_(iOS_and_Android)#Using_FireDAC_to_Connect_to_the_Database):

> - For the mobile platforms, **FireDAC** supports **InterBase ToGo** as well as **SQLite**. These database products can run on iOS and Android devices.
> - For other databases, such as Oracle, you need to have at least a client library. On Windows platforms, the client library is provided as a DLL to connect to. Therefore, you need to develop applications using middle-tier technologies such as DataSnap REST to connect to these database products from a mobile device.

Thus, *Embarcadero* recommends to **use a middle-tier service** (on the database server). For that Delphi ships with **DataSnap**. You can connect to the *Datasnap* server via `TSQLConnection` then.

[A comprehensive tutorial on how to build such a system](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Mobile_Tutorial:_Connecting_to_an_Enterprise_Database_from_a_Mobile_Client_(iOS_and_Android)) for accessing databases from mobile devices can be found in Embarcadero's Docwiki.

Comment: Datasnap is not an option since I am running the database on Azure. I dont intend to install virtual machine just for the datasnap server.